# Online playground to test and compile Underscore templates?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, handlebars.js, web-testing

Is there any online site where we can play around with Underscore or Handlebar templates online without needing to download anything?

Comment: You can play around with underscore in the console on every webpage that has loaded the lib, for example [Underscore.js' own site](http://underscorejs.org/).

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I that's how i was testing it now. I was looking for a more sophisticated way. :)

Comment: You can import external JavaScript libraries through the *Resources* pane on http://jsfiddle.net/, you can do similar things on http://jsbin.com/ as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if underscore templates are enough for your needs: http://rowno.github.io/architect/

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly I think the npm runkit is simpler and easier to use. You can test any npm package on it.

Since *Underscore* and  *Handlebars* are both on npm, there is a runkit for each of them, [Underscore](https://npm.runkit.com/underscore) and [Handlerbars](https://npm.runkit.com/handlebars).

Otherwise, you can use an online code editor like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) and add the libraries you want.

If you want more control over your files and your code you can use something like [glitch](https://glitch.com/) which provides free Node environments that is perfect to test, for example, your serverside script. And if you need a database you can still use [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) alongside with [glitch](https://glitch.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io) has a node.js environment that you can use to install template modules and run them as well, all from the browser.

Comment: I was looking for more of a simple site. Btw its a Cool IDE. Its just wow. Thanx

Comment: Amazing :D ! Thanks Mister @JanJongboom